# How to remove "trigger","start","end" from scrollmagic

Tags: wordpress, scrollmagic

I try to figure out how to remove the "trigger","start","end" when using scrollmagic.

I'm using scrollMagic for wordpress site with Foundation

The problem is that once I remove the call for debug.addIndicators.js, I get an error in the Console:
02:03:49:024 (ScrollMagic.Scene) -> ERROR calling addIndicators() due to missing Plugin 'debug.addIndicators'. Please make sure to include plugins/debug.addIndicators.js

So then I remove this `func.apply(console, args);` from scrollMagic.js and it solves the console error. The question is if this the right thing to do, or there's other solution? because maybe it can affect other elements / functions in the library?

Comment: It sounds to me that you are trying to include the debug functionality but not including the plugin properly. Remember that you need to add the indicator.js separetely.

Comment: So actually I don't really want to include the debug functionality (it's a website I got to work on), but if I not include it, then I also get an error. How / Where I add the  indicator.js separetely?

Comment: Can you post your scrollmagic initialization?